# chamada de INTENT não encontrado

Tags: android, delphi, android-studio, delphi-xe5

O aplicativo delphi chama uma activity de aplicativo java e na chamada apresenta o seguinte erro:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicity activity class {com.embarcadero.pedro.mostraparametrob/actMostraParametros}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManiftst.xml

mas o debug do Android Studio mostra os dois aplicativos rodando.

seguem as listagens

1. aplicativo delphi:

   ```
   var   Intent     : JIntent;

         componente : JComponentName;

         apk,classe : JString;

   begin

         apk         := stringtoJstring('com.embarcadero.pedro.mostraparametrob');

         classe      := stringtoJstring('actMostraParametros');

         componente  := TJComponentName.JavaClass.init(apk,classe);

         Intent      := TJIntent.Create;

         Intent.setAction(apk);

         Intent.setComponent(componente);

         try

         SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);

           except on E: Exception do

             ShowMessage(E.Message);

           end;

   end;
   ```
2. o manifest.xml do app provedor da activity

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.embarcadero.pedro.mostraparametrob" >

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
               android:name=".actMain"
               android:label="@string/app_name" >
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
           <activity
               android:name=".actMostraParametros"
               android:label="actMostraParametros" >
           </activity>
       </application>

   </manifest>
   ```
3. a activity chamada

   ```
   package com.embarcadero.pedro.mostraparametrob;

   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.widget.*;
   import android.view.*;

   public class actMostraParametros extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

       private TextView edtValor1,  edtValor2;
       private Button  btnVoltar;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.act_mostra_parametros);

           edtValor1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edtValor1);
           edtValor2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edtValor2);
           btnVoltar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
           btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(this);

           Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();

           if (bdl.containsKey("para1"))
           {
               String valor1 = bdl.getString("para1");
               edtValor1.setText(valor1);
           }
           if (bdl.containsKey("para2"))
           {
               String valor2 = bdl.getString("para2");
               edtValor2.setText(valor2);
           }

       }

       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           finish();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_act_mostra_parametros, menu);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
           // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
           // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
           int id = item.getItemId();

           //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
           if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
               return true;
           }

           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
   ```